How to get all tokens with a specific supply
Is there any way to get all token on the solana blockchain that have a specific circulating or full supply number (1 000 000 000) for example.

This RPC call will fail because most servers don't allow calling getProgramAccounts with the SPL Token program, but if you had your own unbounded RPC node, you could do getProgramAccounts with a memcmp filter for the supply:
    let mut program_accounts_config = RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
        account_config: RpcAccountInfoConfig {
            encoding: Some(solana_account_decoder::UiAccountEncoding::Base64),
            ..RpcAccountInfoConfig::default()
        },
        ..RpcProgramAccountsConfig::default()
    };

    // Use server-side filtering if only one vote account is provided
    program_accounts_config.filters = Some(vec![
        // Filter by supply
        RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp::new_base58_encoded(36, &desired_supply.to_le_bytes())),
        // Filter by size 82, which is the size of an SPL token mint
        RpcFilterType::DataSize(82)
    ]);

    let all_mints = rpc_client
        .get_program_accounts_with_config(&spl_token::id(), program_accounts_config)?

Adapted from https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/32e8ad2149a9e1af9c67defd342140707629a256/cli/src/cluster_query.rs#L1868
